# C# Moving items that are listed in listbox into another folder

Tags: c#, file, listbox

thank you for your help! I have been trying to list the names of files into Listbox and move the files that are listed into the Listbox into another folder but I couldn't do it. I already got the part on how to list the files into Listbox but the only thing I'm stuck here is that I can't move the listed items from one folder to another folder.

Here is my code for moving the listed items into another folder.

```
string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Business\Music\Example\\";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\Business\Music\SENT\";

            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            string[] sourcefiles = Directory.GetFiles(listBox2.Items.ToString());

            foreach (string sourcefile in sourcefiles)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);
                string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

                File.Copy(sourcefile, destFile, true);
            }
```

Comment: Try to debug your code (insert a breakpoint in this code, ...). you can find yours problem.

Comment: the thing is that I don't have a lots of time to work on this I'm just creating a small solution for a small problem, I'm trying to automate my work instead of doing it one by one.  I'm a newbie in coding so any help would work.

Comment: It would take you 15 minutes to debug this. Take a lunch break and give it a go.